# C++14 errors in C++17, LNK2019, C1001 altogether

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14, auto, cl

##### There's a pretty straightforward 3-file source.

Compiling with **cl.exe**.

- Using **/std:c++17** it compiles with **c++14** errors (***error C3533**: a parameter cannot have a type that contains 'auto'*).
- Using **/std:c++20** it compiles but gives an **LNK2019**.
- When using **/std:c++20**, **BUT WITH** `#include <string>` moved from ***serialization.cpp*** => ***database.h***, it gives a *fatal internal compiler **error C1001***.

---

##### The source files:

*database.h:*

```
#pragma once

#include <map>

struct map_manip 
{
    void operator()(auto& map, uint8_t size = 2);
};
```

*database.cpp:*

```
#include "database.h"

void map_manip::operator()(auto& map, uint8_t size)
{
}
```

*serialization.cpp:*

```
#include "database.h"

#include <string>

struct entry
{
    std::map<std::string_view, uint32_t> units;
};

int main()
{
    entry x;
    map_manip y;
    y(x.units);
}
```

---

##### Compiling with c++17:

```
D:\dev\Local\Test>cl /EHsc /std:c++17 serialization.cpp database.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.29.30133 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

serialization.cpp
D:\dev\Local\Test\database.h(8): error C3533: a parameter cannot have a type that contains 'auto'
serialization.cpp(12): error C2664: 'void map_manip::operator ()(unknown-type,uint8_t)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::map<std::string_view,uint32_t,std::less<std::string_view>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string_view,uint32_t>>>' to 'unknown-type'
D:\dev\Local\Test\database.h(8): note: see declaration of 'map_manip::operator ()'
database.cpp
D:\dev\Local\Test\database.h(8): error C3533: a parameter cannot have a type that contains 'auto'
database.cpp(3): error C3533: a parameter cannot have a type that contains 'auto'
Generating Code...
```

These errors would've been valid in **c++14**, I believe, but shouldn't be the case here as we compile with **c++17**. Correct me if I get it wrong, please.

---

##### Compiling with c++20:

```
D:\dev\Local\Test>cl /EHsc /std:c++20 serialization.cpp database.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.29.30133 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

serialization.cpp
database.cpp
Generating Code...
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.29.30133.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:serialization.exe
serialization.obj
database.obj
serialization.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall map_manip::operator()<class std::map<class std::basic_string_view<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >,unsigned int,struct std::less<class std::basic_string_view<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > >,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<class std::basic_string_view<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > const ,unsigned int> > > >(class std::map<class std::basic_string_view<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >,unsigned int,struct std::less<class std::basic_string_view<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > >,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<class std::basic_string_view<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > const ,unsigned int> > > &,unsigned char)" (??$?RV?$map@V?$basic_string_view@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IU?$less@V?$basic_string_view@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBV?$basic_string_view@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@I@std@@@2@@std@@@map_manip@@QAEXAAV?$map@V?$basic_string_view@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IU?$less@V?$basic_string_view@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBV?$basic_string_view@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@I@std@@@2@@std@@E@Z) referenced in function _main
serialization.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Honestly, I do not get this error at all, but it seems like it's somehow connected to the **auto**. Even though changing **auto** to **template** does not change a thing, if we remove `auto& map` from `void operator()` arguments (both ***database.h*** and ***database.cpp***), then it compiles to .exe just fine!

---

##### Compiling with c++20 and moving `#include <string>` from *serialization.cpp* => *database.h*

*database.h:*

```
#pragma once

#include <map>
#include <string>

struct map_manip 
{
    void operator()(auto& map, uint8_t size = 2);
};
```

*serialization.cpp:*

```
#include "database.h"

struct entry
{
    std::map<std::string_view, uint32_t> units;
};

int main()
{
    entry x;
    map_manip y;
    y(x.units);
}
```

In this case I just get an internal compiler error. It feel I should report this to MSVC developers but still provide it here as well, just in case.

```
D:\dev\Local\Test>cl /EHsc /std:c++20 serialization.cpp database.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.29.30133 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

serialization.cpp
serialization.cpp(5): fatal error C1001: Internal compiler error.
(compiler file 'msc1.cpp', line 1603)
 To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
If possible please provide a repro here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com
Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
 Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
INTERNAL COMPILER ERROR in 'C:\dev\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe'
    Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
    Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
```

Any ideas would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. `auto` in function parameter list makes an [abbreviated function template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Abbreviated_function_template), a C++20 feature
2. As the function is template, you need to move the function definition to header, as usual with templates, to make the program link; see [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/2945027)
3. Report ICE to https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/home or via *Help > Send Feedback > Report a problem...* from Visual Studio

Comment: Thank you so much! I've already reported the issue to MS.
I've also tested the code with some changes and with CLang:                         
~ cl.exe crashes regardless of whether the function implementation is in the header file or not.               
~ CLang, on the other hand, compiles perfectly fine with your advice (1 and 2) implemented.